# In vueJS I want to get actual value of the checkbox but I just get true or undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In vueJS I want to get actual value of the checkbox but I just get true or undefined. 
Here is source code of checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" :value="assessment" :id="assessment+index" class="md-check" v-model="form.assessments[index]">
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `true-value` and `false-value`. See the docs: [Checkbox](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox-1):

> ```
> <input
>   type="checkbox"
>   v-model="toggle"
>   true-value="yes"
>   false-value="no"
> >
>
> // when checked:
> vm.toggle === 'yes'
> // when unchecked:
> vm.toggle === 'no'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

For a single checkbox you can use `true-value` and `false-value` attributes; for multiple checkboxes, use an array for the v-model:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: ["One"]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Foo" v-model="foo" value="One"> One<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Foo" v-model="foo" value="Two"> Two<br>
  v-model value is: {{foo}}
</div>
```